# How to call api of circleCI

Tags: github, circleci

I recenly use circleCI to auto deploy my project.
The problem is that I can call api for my own project via "https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/my_account_name/my_project_name", but when I call the same api with project of other organization (this project also included in my github repositories) it show me the error "Project not found": "https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/user_name/project_name".

I call that url via postman.
What wrong am I doing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I can call the api.
The api must include circle-token of organizaion's project within circleCI:
https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/user_name/project_name?circle-token=created_token"